# Can't load image in my django template

Tags: python, django, templates, web, django-templates

My project folders is  :

```
mrdoorbeen
manage.py
    mr_doorbeen
         setting.py
    mrdoorbeen
      migrations
      templates
         index.html
         profile
             profile.html
```

I want to include a image in my `profile.html` file.
i use `{% load staticfiles %}` in top of the `profile.html`and use this code at image source :

```
<img src="{% static "image/example.jpg" %}" alt="cant'load"/>
```

and i make a folder in a `mr_doorbeen` and call it `static` and in static folder make a `image` folder and image i put a `example.jpg` but it doesn't work . **my** `static` **folder path is wrong or what?**
**where should i put** my `static` folder in this project

Comment: what is your static file configuration in settings?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given directory structure, You can put your static files on same level as of the directory  with file, `mr_doorbeen/settings.py`

```
mrdoorbeen
manage.py
    mr_doorbeen
      setting.py
    mrdoorbeen
      migrations
      templates
         index.html
         profile
             profile.html
    static/
```

You can set the static files to the said location as follows.

```
# Static files configurations.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: Tnx.i will do it .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your settings file where you need to define     `STATIC_URL`. Just follow the description in [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Can you explain more?i don't khow what are you say!

Comment: Should i put **static** folder next of **setting.py**

Comment: Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Also what is the path of your image? You need to store your file in a folder called `static` in your app. Then you can use `{% static "example.jpg" %}` in your template.

Comment: You can also follow the file structure and static file path [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files).

Comment: Where should i put **static** folder.i dont khow just where is exactly place of folder.      Next of **views.py** or **setting.py**

Comment: Put your template and static folder with the same level with mr_doorbeen folder. Then define `STATIC_URL = '/static/' and STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)` in your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it by adding to my settings file the import of os from pathlib and the STATICFILES_DIRS line provided in one of the other responses:

```
from pathlib import Path, os

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

STATIC_URL was already properly specified to '/static/'.  I couldnt solve the problem with just the STATICFILES line until I realized os is a function in pathlib that needed to be imported first.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to importing os and adding the line just mentioned, copying the image files under static directly from within a folder that was under static (named after the app) was key to making it work.  I kept the files in the folder under static too so there was redundancy.

After I did that, it worked, and then I could then delete the image files under static directly (not touching those within the folder under static) and it still worked.  Somehow, copying them directly under static "taught" Django to access the files within the folder under static, which I dont understand, but it worked.